# Huge Array filtering

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I am using realm db and in my table I have 100000 record. After request for new data I need to check this data exist in my table or not.

I am getting the record in array from db. And every request I am checking new record exist in this array or not. I use first, map, filter, foreach and for loops. But all of them increase memory so much and then application freeze.

How can I search in huge array without any memory problem?

My table structure:

userName - UserPhone - userAddres

```
let users = [User]() --Filled from realm db.

let realm = try! Realm()

let userData = realm.objects(Users.self)    
users = Array(userData)

let userItem = self.users.first(where: { $0.userName == item.Name && $0.userPhone == item.phone })

let userItem = self.users.filter(where: { $0.userName == item.Name && $0.userPhone == item.phone })
```

Comment: Why can you not run a query to Realm instead of getting all users to begin with? https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries

Comment: I already try it but again memory problem occurs

Comment: Show the code you use to run the query.

Comment: Also... there’s some serious questioning to be done around how the app can access all the other users data. That data should be locked down so that the app can only access the current users information. From the code above it looks like you are leaking all users’ names and phone numbers?!?

Comment: This my code for getting user data from db
let item = database.objects(Userss.self)
        
        return Array(item)

Comment: Edit your question to put the code in. Don’t put code into the comments.

Comment: yes... in this you are getting all users. A query can specify which users to get. You pass the phone number and name into the query and it will return only the relevant users.

Comment: I already they it and memory increases again. Bacause I am requesting data in for loop (13 request) and for every request has around 100 record. It means I need to go to db for all records.

Comment: But why are you getting so many records? If you know what you need then only request the records that you need. You should not be filtering the array after the request.